# A probability problem with maximum and summation

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_n$ be iid nonnegative r.v.s, suppose there exists positive sequence $a_n$ such that $S_n/a_n\xrightarrow[]{P}1$, then show $$\max_{1\le i\le n} X_i/S_n\xrightarrow[]{P}0.$$
I have shown that  $\max_{1\le i\le n} X_i\xrightarrow[]{P}0$ iff $nP(X_1>\epsilon a_n)\rightarrow 0$ and any help for showing $nP(X_1>\epsilon a_n)\rightarrow 0$ using $S_n/a_n\xrightarrow[]{P}1$ would be helpful. 
Thanks!

Comment: Surely you need a growth restriction on the sequence $(a_n)$ (because such a sequence always exists). Any other information on the dependence/distribution of the involved random variables?

Comment: REALLY SORRY! IT IS $\frac{S_n}{a_n}\xrightarrow[]{P}1$, and I think the hint is to show if $nP(X_1>\epsilon a_n)$ does not converge, then it contradicts $\frac{S_n}{a_n}\xrightarrow[]{P}1$.

Comment: It seems you assume that the $X_n$ have the same distribution. Is it the case in your problem?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your patience!

Comment: I changed the problem again, use IID

Answer (score 0):

We can use a symmetrization argument: take $(X'_i)_i$ and $(X''_i)$ two independent i.i.d. sequences, where $X'_1$ and $X''_1$ have the same distribution as $X_1$. Using Lévy's inequality 
$$\mathbb P\left(\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}|S_j|\gt x\right)\leqslant 2\mathbb P( |S_n|\gt x) ,$$
we get that 
$$\frac 1{a_n}  \max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}|X'_j-X''_j  | \to 0 $$
in probability.